# Cancelling interval when a given value is reached

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Where do I put clearInterval when progressState is greater than 99 in my App?

```
  const [progressState, setProgress] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => { setProgress(progressState => progressState + 1);}, 1000);
  }, []); // this is only called once because of [], now i can't check for clearing
```

I am confused because of Functional Programming, even adding 1+1 is becoming a nightmare.

Do I have to use another useEffect method to clear the interval?

**I did this now**

```
  const [progressState, setProgress] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setProgress(progressState => {
        progressState == 100 && clearInterval(interval)
        return progressState + 1;
      });
    }, 100);
  }, []);
```

Comment: Using `setInterval` is a bit unintuitive with functional components and react hooks. It's probably easier to use something like `useInterval` (https://github.com/donavon/use-interval) for now. If you want a deeper understanding of it, this is a great write-up https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Comment: Btw I didn't have anything do to with the creation of `useInterval` even though our names are similar haha

Comment: i already stumbled upon this... thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the handler function.

```
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  setProgress(progressState => progressState + 1);
  if (progressState >= 99) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: this is funny, progressState is 0 all the time. code won't work

Comment: I really don't get why it remains 0 but i tried to put the conditional inside the setProgress callback now, and it seems to work